# Сколько банок разного объема понадобиться, чтобы закрасить указанную пользователем площадь (Есть ли алгоритм?)

Tags: javascript, python, php, java, c#

Пользователь вводит площадь поверхности, которую надо ему закрасить, есть 3 банки с разным объемом

```
[
{"id":"1","Цена":"2691.0000","Эта банка закрашивает площадь":"7"},
  {"id":"2","Цена":"5520.0000","Эта банка закрашивает площадь":"17.5"},
  {"id":"3","Цена":"9260.0000","Эта банка закрашивает площадь":"31.5"}
]
```

У каждой банки известно какую площадь он закрашивает и сколько она стоит.
Как рассчитать сколько банок каких объемов нужно чтобы закрасить введенную пользователем площадь.

---

К примеру, пользователь указал 60 кв/м значит нужно 2 банки по 31.5 Есть какой ни будь алгоритм для нахождения самого оптимального варианта?

---

Нужно посчитать сколько банок какого объема нужно, что бы закрасить указанную пользователем площадь.
Пытаюсь написать функцию с входными данными

```
function (paints: json, area: double)
```

где **paints** это банки с красками

```
[
{"id":"1","Цена":"2691.0000","Эта банка закрашивает площадь":"7"},
  {"id":"2","Цена":"5520.0000","Эта банка закрашивает площадь":"17.5"},
  {"id":"3","Цена":"9260.0000","Эта банка закрашивает площадь":"31.5"}
]
```

а **area** это площадь, которую указал пользователь.
Выходные данные массив id банок, которые нужны для закрашивания заданной площади

```
["3","3","2"]
```

Функция подойдет на любом языке программирования

Comment: Пытаюсь написать функцию - покажите попытки

Comment: Пытался написать с помощью циклов while, но пока ничего не выходит, пытаюсь придумать алгоритм какой нибудь

Comment: как придумаете, пишите код и возможные проблемы, будем его обсуждать

Comment: Хорошо спасибо.

Comment: прежде чем искать оптимальный вариант нужно определить в чем заключается оптимальность. Если нужно использовать как можно меньше банок - один критерий. Нужно, чтобы осталось как можно меньше неиспользованной краски - другой критерий. Потратить меньше всего денег - третий. В зависимости от критерия решения будут разными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам наверное нужно минимальное количество банок (для оптимизации цены)? Напишите что значит оптимально - дешевле?
Если нет условия, что банки должны быть использованы полностью, то алгоритм простой:

1. делим площадь на площадь покраски самой большой банки нацело. Получаем количество больших банок и остаток незакрашенной площади (остаток от деления).
2. делим незакрашенную площадь на площадь покраски средней банки нацело. Получаем количество средних банок и остаток незакрашенной площади.
3. делим незакрашенную площадь на площадь покраски маленькой банки нацело. Получаем количество маленьких банок и делаем +1 на остаток незакрашенной площади.

Comment: Оптимально, главное что бы площадь была закрашена, спасибо

Comment: Оптимально может быть разным! Навскидку: 1.дешевле 2.меньше осталось неиспользованной краски 3.меньше банок в штуках использовано. В зависимости от критерия подбирается алгоритм.

Comment: "площадь была закрашена" - это результат. А ещё нужен критерий оптимальности (оценочная функция).

Comment: Пока делаю на скорость, но потом надо будет под оптимальную цену подбирать

Comment: Вообще говоря, нет никакой гарантии, что большая банка будет стоить меньше, чем две банки вдвое меньшего объёма. Соответственно, в п. 1 надо брать не самую большую, а самую выгодную банку.

Comment: @Yaant В первом куске кода есть цена банки и площадь, на которую её хватает. Самая большая - самая выгодная. Ну и банки не ровно вдвое меньшего размера.

Comment: @DmitryK Полагаете, входные данные для задачи могут быть только такими? Так тогда и алгоритм не нужен, достаточно функции из одной строчки `return ["3", "3"]`, и все.

Comment: @Yaant Я не полагаю - я не знаю. Я спросил у автора, какой критерий ему нужен. Ответа нет. Возможно там будут ещё ограничения. Мой алгоритм приближен к реальности  - самая большая банка -> самый дешевый 1 кв.м. покраски. Пока не знаем всех критериев и ограничений, спорить ни о чем можно до бесконечности. Я написал самый простенький алгоритм, не претендующий на истину в последней инстанции, т.к. автор вообще не знал, за что хвататься. Напишите свой - большой, хороший, учитывающий любые входные данные и т.д.

Comment: @DmitryK Я использовал ваш алгоритм, плюс внутри учитывал стоимость банки, все работает хорошо, спасибо за помощь